# Has anyone mentioned this site on the ARocket mailing list?

Tags: discussion

I follow the [ARocket mailing list](http://exrocketry.net/mailman/listinfo/arocket) but this is full of serious Amatuer rocket folk.  Like Henry Spencer, and others, so I am severely intimidated from posting.

I was wondering if anyone else seriously participates in it and has mentioned this site on it?

Comment: I don't, but I would strongly encourage you to post a link to us there - it can't hurt, and will probably do a whole lot of good.